# HTML/CSS - Sidebar Length 100% Page Height, Regardless of Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this has been asked quite some times however after quite some time searching for a solution I have finally resorted to asking a question here!

I am working on an HTML Help file for an application I am developing, where the file is split into two sections. One, a sidebar (floated to the left) and two, the main content section (also floating left).

The problem I am facing is that when the main content extends beyond 100% of the page height, the sidebar background stops.

I would use the faux column effect where I assign the  a background image of my sidebar however to maintain my design's integrity I have to set a different background image for the body.

Check out this JS Fiddle I set up - http://jsfiddle.net/5gpFx/

Hopefully that can help you see what the issue is if I failed to communicate it well enough!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap both columns in a container and set the faux-column background on that - this way the body will be available for setting whatever image you want. I've made a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5gpFx/2/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I could not make work the solution with flexboxes above. So I created my own template, that includes:

- a header with a fixed size element
- a footer
- a side bar with a scrollbar that occupies the remaining height
- content

I used flexboxes but in a more simple way, using only properties **display: flex** and **flex-direction: row|column**:

I do use angular and I want my component sizes to be 100% of their parent element.

The key is to set the size (in percents) for all parents inorder to limit their size. In the following example myapp height has 100% of the viewport.

The main component has 90% of the viewport, because header and footer have 5%.

I posted my template here: https://jsfiddle.net/abreneliere/mrjh6y2e/3

```
       body{
        margin: 0;
        color: white;
        height: 100%;
    }
    div#myapp
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: red; /* <-- painful color for your eyes ! */
        height: 100%; /* <-- if you remove this line, myapp has no limited height */
    }
    div#main /* parent div for sidebar and content */
    {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90%; 
    }
    div#header {
        background-color: #333;
        height: 5%;
    }
    div#footer {
        background-color: #222;
        height: 5%;
    }
    div#sidebar {
        background-color: #666;
        width: 20%;
        overflow-y: auto;
     }
    div#content {
        background-color: #888;
        width: 80%;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    div.fized_size_element {
        background-color: #AAA;
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
```

Html:

```
<body>
<div id="myapp">
    <div id="header">
        HEADER
        <div class="fized_size_element"></div>

    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="sidebar">
            SIDEBAR
            <div class="fized_size_element"></div>
            <div class="fized_size_element"></div>
            <div class="fized_size_element"></div>
            <div class="fized_size_element"></div>
            <div class="fized_size_element"></div>
            <div class="fized_size_element"></div>
            <div class="fized_size_element"></div>
            <div class="fized_size_element"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```